# java ExecutorService, changing fixedsize

Tags: java, multithreading

So I want to change the fixedthreadpool size after already declaring it before, how would I go about doing this. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
 //pool has 21 threads in queue 

 //do somestuff

 network sends a change in thread limit signal when there are 12 threads left in queue
 //redeclare:
      pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

But it doesn't work, only 3 threads continue to be excuted at a time.

I think I know what the problem is: the executor stores the 21 threads in queue and wont change the fixed thread pool size till the queue is cleared.
I don't want this, How would I make it so that the change in threadpoolsize affects the entire queue? Would I need to reload the entire queue (if so, How would i do that)?

Answer (score 6):

Creating a new pool does get rid of the old one, unless you shut it down you now have two pools, one with three threads and one with four.

The simplest thing to do is to create a ThreadPoolExecutor (which is the implementing class here)  This will allow you to change the core pool size and the maximum pool times.

```
// start with a pool with a min/max size of 3.
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3,3,60, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

// set the min/max size to 4.
executor.setMaximumPoolSize(4);
executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
```

Another option is to make the pool size 4 from the start if you know that 4 is reasonable.

Comment: I want to set the default to be 3, but depending on the task workload, i want to change the limit. For instance, some tasks can take a long time so I want to keep it at 3, but some can take a short time so I want to increase it to 5 (for example). I just need an idea on how to accomplish this.

Comment: @user3773673 You can resize the limit up and down as above.  If you have tasks you know are long and others you know are short, I would use two pools say a pool of 3 for long tasks and a pool of 2 for short tasks.  This way a short task will never be waiting for a long task.  If you have five long tasks in the queue and you add a short task, it will wait for a long task to finish even if you resize to 5.  If you have 5 tasks in one pool and add a short task to an empty pool, it will start straight away.  Then there is no need to be dynamically resizing pools.